# AES File Encryption/Decryption

Tags: java, file, encryption, aes, dropbox

**Objective:** To pick File with JFileChooser take that File pass it into encryption method, encrypt file get the encrypted file then finally upload the file to a server via. the upload method I have or more specifically the particular line of code '*uploadedFile = client.uploadFile( "/" + nameOf ,DbxWriteMode.add(), inputFile.length(),his);'*

**Problem:** Normal upload works fine without the encryption involved  when trying to encrypt file will not go through along with the "KEY" not being able to be put into the inputFile and the server will not accept the file please see code.

**Question:** How to integrate the encryption into this for the code to work appropriately and effectively combining my uploadFile method and the encryption methods that I have

**Working Code Below This Has NO Encryption**

```
public void uploadFile() throws DbxException, FileLoadException, 

IOException, Exception {

    try{

        //auth method

        phoneHome();

    }catch(IOException e){

        System.out.println("not saving accessToken");

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your Access Information Does 
Not Exist,\n Please Login"+
                "Please Login By Clicking 'OK'");
        drop(); // will run auth method for user to login
    }
    fc = new JFileChooser();
    fc.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
    fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
    int dialog = fc.showSaveDialog(this);
    if (dialog == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        inputFile = fc.getSelectedFile();
        inputFile.getName();
        inputFile.getAbsoluteFile();
        String nameOf = inputFile.getName();
        System.out.println(" File: " + inputFile);


        fis = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
// where the file is being sent to upload to dropbox
        uploadedFile = client.uploadFile( "/" + nameOf ,DbxWriteMode.add(), inputFile.length(),fis);
            }

    communication.append("");
    System.out.println("Uploaded: " + uploadedFile.toString());
    communication.append("Uploaded: " + uploadedFile.toString());


    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"File Upload:" + uploadedFile.toString(),
                   "Success!", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);



        }
```

**Methods That I Have For Encryption That Need To Be Implemented Above**

```
private byte[] getKeyBytes(final byte[] key) throws Exception {
        byte[] keyBytes = new byte[16];
        System.arraycopy(key, 0, keyBytes, 0, Math.min(key.length, keyBytes.length));
        return keyBytes;
    }

    public Cipher getCipherEncrypt(final byte[] key) throws Exception {
        byte[] keyBytes = getKeyBytes(key);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
        IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(keyBytes);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, ivParameterSpec);
        return cipher;
    }
public void encrypt() throws Exception {
        Cipher cipher = getCipherEncrypt(key);
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        CipherOutputStream cos = null;
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        try {
           fis = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
         fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
            cos = new CipherOutputStream(fos, cipher);
            byte[] data = new byte[1024];
            int read = fis.read(data);
            while (read != -1) {
                cos.write(data, 0, read);
                read = fis.read(data);
                System.out.println(new String(data, "UTF-8").trim());
            }
            cos.flush();
        } finally {
            cos.close();
            fos.close();
            fis.close();
        }
    }
```

**Ideas For Putting These Guys Together?**

Comment: Please format your code nicely first. With all these empty lines, it is no pleasure to read.

Comment: will fix it right now, apologies

Answer (score 0):

***First check:* make original file into zip and upload it**

if it works then make you encrypted file into zip and then send via dropbox

Comment: Regardless of what file extension I am trying to upload it is not in relevance to the question. They pick the file with the JFileChooser and then the inputFile is the file in which they just picked passed and uploaded to their server. What i am trying to do is do the same exact thing but instead run through the encryption after the file has been picked and then passed to be uploaded